# Java Generics compile time error and raw types

Tags: java, generics

As per jls8 doc, it is compile time error if parameterized type is not well formed..According to doc,

> A parameterized type C is well-formed if all of the
>   following are true:
>
> - C is the name of a generic type.
> - The number of type arguments is the same as the number of type    parameters in the generic declaration of C.
> - When subjected to capture conversion (§5.1.10) resulting in the type    C, each type argument Xi is a subtype of
>     S[F1:=X1,...,Fn:=Xn] for each bound type S in Bi.
>
> It is a compile-time error if a parameterized type is not well-formed.

But raw types are not well formed as per point number 2..Why is it legal to declare a variable as:

```
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
```

Comment: A raw type is not a parameterized type, so these rules for parameterized types do not apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [JLS 8 Sec 4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.5):

> A parameterized type is a class or interface type of the form `C<T1,...,Tn>` ...

A raw type doesn't have the `<>` or any of the `T` parameters. Thus, it's not a parameterized type, so the rules you quote are not applicable.